# Change number in string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in an excel-sheet like this:

```
a_bcdfg02fga
k_lmnop05fab
x_yzabd03ea
```

I would like to substract the number by 1 in these string to get a column like this

```
a_bcdfg01fga
k_lmnop04fab
x_yzabd02ea
```

I never face such a problem so I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Are the numbers always two digits?  Do they always land on the 8th character in the string? Are they always the only numbers in the string?

Comment: @scott craner yes to all

Comment: Are Position & Length of "number" always the same? Pos=8 and Len=2 ?? (if not, then figure out what those values for each row).  Separate into 3 parts, subtract 1 from part 2, recombine 3 parts back into one.

Comment: And... Is range of numbers from 01-09? Or can it be 01-99?

Comment: Position and Length of number is always the same and len is also always two. Its all exactly like in the example I gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,7)&text(MID(A1,8,2)-1,"00")&MID(a1,10,20)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, this works perfectly.